# JVM crash with segmentation fault

Tags: java, segmentation-fault, garbage-collecting

We have a cluster of tomcat servers, just upgraded to debian7/openjdk7/tomcat7 (all from stock debian). Now we had two JVM crash on different machines. Both servers having identical hardware and are configured exactly the same (besides IP Addresses of course)

First Crash:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fd0b582123a, pid=6542, tid=140533723084544
#
# JRE version: 7.0_25-b30
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x62623a]  LinkResolver::runtime_resolve_interface_method(CallInfo&, methodHandle, KlassHandle, Handle, KlassHandle, bool, Thread*)+0x5a
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fd0948b0800):  JavaThread "catalina30" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=6670, stack(0x00007fd08e94b000,0x00007fd08ea4c000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000000
```

Second Crash:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f0a3a22421d, pid=3454, tid=139681826494208
#
# JRE version: 7.0_25-b30
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x71021d]  ParRootScanWithBarrierTwoGensClosure::do_oop(unsigned int*)+0x6d
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000000088c000):  GCTaskThread [stack: 0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000] [id=3781]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000018
```

We never had any JVM crash before.

I really don't know where to start. Does it look like a hardware fault? JDK Bug? Tomcat Bug?

What is the most probably reason for this?

Comment: try to start tomcat using the oracle java jdk

Comment: Isn't oracle jdk and openjdk the same or mostly the same? Is this a bug filed anywhere or is it just a wild guess that oraclejdk is more stable because they won the americas cup?

Comment: openjdk vs oracle jdk, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977238/why-should-i-use-the-oracle-jdk-over-the-openjdk-or-vice-versa

Comment: Agree with the other commenters...  At least as a first troubleshooting step.

Comment: Also if this is an upgrade from jdk6 - jdk7 I'd also want to try pointing back at a jdk6 to see if that clears it up and if it does then you have a direction to look in for code changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were issues with my RAM. We have new RAM in the servers and now everything works. I have tested both OracleJDK and OpenJDK afterwards and I can't see any differences in performance or functionality. The only thing missing in Oracle JDK is full cryptography. So I prefer OpenJDK from now on.